# Is there a workaround for Postman's bug when content is returned with a 204?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

Using Postman, when I make a PUT request to an endpoint which returns a 204 *with content*, Postman is unable to parse the response, and my collection runner stops that iteration, indicating that an error has occurred.

When run outside of the runner, Postman displays the following:

[image: postman error]

[Other people have also had this problem](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2418)

Unfortunately I cannot fix the non-standard endpoint. Is there a workaround that will let Postman continue without throwing an error, especially when using the collection runner?

Answer (score 0):

The 204 (204 NO CONTENT) response from the server means that the server processed your request  successfully and a response is not needed.

More here: https://httpstatuses.com/204

Actually as much as I know, if the server is sending a 204 with a payload response, the endpoint is not developed as it should.

This would be the main reason Postman is not showing a response payload. You will only be able to read response headers.

So if you send a PUT request, and only receive headers, it means everything is ok. If you spect data the server should be responding with a 200 code.

Now, said this, if postman is telling you that “it could not get any response” it means basically the server is not responding any thing. Now try to increase the timeout in the postman settings. It’s very probable that the server is taking to much time. Check outside the runner how much time it’s taking to response.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: given that postman is used for API development, i think that it should be able to cope with non-standard responses.